# How do you use panel data to isolate the relationship of interest for a particular individual within your panel?

Tags: regression, econometrics, interaction, panel-data, random-effects-model

I have a panel data set where Canadian provinces are the individuals. (I have annual data from 1997-2017).

I am using a random effects model to see the impact of an explanatory variable $X_{it}$ on a dependent variable $Y_{it}$ (as well as many controls) at a national level.

I'm also interested in just seeing the relationship for one province $j$. i.e. What effect did $X$ have on $Y$ only in province $j$ Is there any way to use my panel data to answer this question? Could I create a dummy for province $j$ and then interact it with $X_{it}$?

Comment: Can you clarify how $_{}$ changes over time for each province and across provinces?

Comment: $X_{it}$ is the capital-to-labour ratio within the healthcare sector in each province in each year. So it is a continuous variable that differs somewhat (but not hugely) between provinces and either trends gradually up or down over time within each province.

Answer (score 1):

You want to run your model with $X_{it}$, a dummy for province $j$, and the interaction of the dummy and $X_{it}$ on the right-hand-side. The coefficient on the interaction will tell you if $X$ has an unusual effect in that province (relative to the others).

You might also want to interact your other covariates with the province $j$ dummy.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Do you mean RHS (instead of LHS)?

Comment: @leecarvallo Yes, I mean the other left. Let me fix.

Comment: Hi again Dimitriy, why should I interact my other covariates (my controls) with the province $j$ dummy as well?

Comment: @leecarvallo Obviously, context matters and you should not put in interactions willy nilly, but use domain expertise. However, if you are worried that $X$ has a different effect in province $j$, that concern may apply to other covariates.

Comment: I see, thank you. So I should add interactions where conceptually there may be different effects between provinces?

Comment: @leecarvallo Yes, it would be a kind of a robustness check.